# How to prove the following curious approximation to $\sin (A/2)$

Tags: trigonometry

In the article "Concerning haversines in plane trigonometry" by G. W. Evans, the following approximate formula is mentioned without proof:

$ \sin \frac{A}{2} \approx \sqrt{\frac{c-b}{2c}}$

Here $c $ is the hypotenuse, and $ b $ is a side which is nearly equal to $c$.

The question is: How to derive this approximation?

NOTE: For some reason, I can't send comments. Now I see that this is not an approximation, but I was confused because in the article, $ b $ is supposed to be nesrly equal to $ c$, but I see that this is not necessary. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hypotenuse of which triangle?

Comment: If $c$ is nearly equal to $b$, does that mean the triangle approximates an isosceles triangle?

Comment: The paper says "$b$, nearly equal to $c$". I wonder why, this is not required.

Comment: This is just the well-kown half-angle formula $$\sin\frac\alpha2=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\alpha}2}.$$

Comment: @YvesDaoust despite the word 'hypotenuse', perhaps the text is only assuming  an 'almost' right angle triangle. José, can you comment?

Comment: @peterag: in the paper, "For the case where a right triangle is given...". This leaves little doubt I guess. Also note that the author uses a plain $=$, not $\approx$.

Answer (score 5):

We have $\sin A=\frac{a}{c}$. Using $\sin A=2\sin\frac{A}{2}\cos\frac{A}{2}$ and putting $s=\sin\frac{A}{2}$ we get $s^2(1-s^2)=\frac{a^2}{4c^2}$, so $s^4-s^2+\frac{a^2}{4c^2}=0$. Solving the quadratic we get $s^2=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-a^2/c^2}}{2}$.

Since the triangle is right-angled, we have $c^2=a^2+b^2$, so $\sqrt{1-a^2/c^2}=\frac{b}{c}$, and hence $s^2=\frac{c\pm b}{2c}$.

But $\angle A<90^o$, so $\angle\frac{A}{2}<45^o$ and hence $s^2<\frac{1}{2}$. Hence we must choose the negative sign and we have finally $s=\sqrt{\frac{c-b}{2c}}$. Note that there is no approximation.

Comment: I was getting to that - alternatively: to be shown: $$ \sin^2 A/2 =  {1 - \cos A \over 2} \approx { c - b \over 2c } = 1/2 ( 1 - (b/c) ),$$
iff $\cos A \approx b/c$. If $c$ is the hypotenuse, and $b$ adjacent to $A$,  this is equality.

Comment: @peterag Yes, that is definitely neater. I am afraid I wasted part of my youth in math contests and so tend to go with the first thing that works, rather than the neatest!

Comment: I never had the brains for math contests - but, as you point out, at least I am probably a neat dresser. What a consolation... (+1, btw)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, more of a clarification. This is an example of what I think the situation is that we are dealing with:

[image: GeoGebra picture]

Comment: The relation is exact, there is no need for a short side.